# Timer to control the bluetooth scan time

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm currently working with a Bluetooth module, for which my application automatically scans in order auto-connect.

What i'm trying to achieve though, is to implement a restriction in terms of the amount of time that the application is allowed to scan for the module. I figured that it made good sense to use `system.threading.Timer` for this purpose, to run behind code.

```
if(c = 1)
    {
     bleText.Text = "Scanning...";
     Scan_Function(); 
    }
Private void Scan_Function()
{
 //Timer stuff
}
```

However, i'm unaware if this is the correct way of doing it, and how i might be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a timer, just get the time when task starts and subtract it from the time it ends:

```
Private void Scan_Function()
{
    DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
    //Timer stuff
    double milliSecondsElapsed = (DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliSeconds;
}
```

Of course you can use these 2 lines outside the method too:

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
Scan_Function()
double milliSecondsElapsed = (DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliSeconds;
```